# Angular 7 - Service Worker PWA + SSR not working on server

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering, angular-service-worker

I am struggling to make my Server Side Rendering and Service Worker cooperate on server Side.

**Information regarding localhost** -> Working

This is working as expected. The service worker works and updates my app on every update. Moreover; a `curl localhost:8082` send me back my info.

I start my app with the following command : `npm run ssr`

```
 "ssr": "npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr",
 "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles",
 "serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
 "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && npm run webpack:server",
 "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
```

**Information regarding production:** -> Not Working

Website is over HTTPS : https://airdropers.io
Website process is running on a close port and has HAPROXY redirecting traffic from 443 to the port of the webserver

> Issue visible on Webserver logs : Could not subscribe to notifications
>   Error: Service workers are disabled or not supported by this browser

**Extra info :**

Node js on localhost and production are the same: v9.0.0
I build on production with the following process :

1. git pull
2. npm run build:ssr
3. pm2 start dist/server.js

**UPDATE 23/02/2019**

I have now a deeper understanding.
My issue is that I start my SSR/PWA server with a node command such as "node dist/server.js".

From my understanding "node dist/server.js" is not working for Service Worker (PWA) 
I quote (https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started)

> Because ng serve does not work with service workers, you must use a
>   separate HTTP server to test your project locally. You can use any
>   HTTP server. The example below uses the http-server package from npm.
>   To reduce the possibility of conflicts and avoid serving stale
>   content, test on a dedicated port and disable caching.

I can not launch is with `http-server dist/browser` because I will loose the SSR Capability.

How can I start my PWA / SSR Server ? 
What command shall I use?
What build shall I do?

**UPDATE 24/02/2019**

As mentioned by @Gökhan Kurt the service worker is not working properly with my SSR server. 
I need SSR for SEO and I need a service worker for Browser Push Notification. 
What solution do I have to handle Browser User Push Notification? A third party lib such as One Signals?

---

Any ideas suggestions are well welcomed to help me make that work.
Thank you for support,
Alex

Comment: It sounds like you need to gate the service worker install to not try to register in the node environment.

Comment: What do you mean @abraham ? I am keen to follow any clue and idea possible.

Comment: stupid question maybe...  Does the connection need to be end-to-end in https for this to work?  The reverse proxy terminates the SSL?

Comment: I have now a deeper understanding of my issue.
I will share updates now.

Comment: @aorfevre did you got resolve this issue

Comment: @aorfevre can you put the complete solution for SSR for SEO support & PWA ? It will be very helpful. Can't find any other resource which explains this.

Comment: @aorfevre Hi. Have you implemeted PWA + SSR ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is actually not related to your server at all. The problem is, service worker is tried to be registered on the server side, which is not supported. What you can do is make it so that service worker will register on client side.

I haven't tried but this just may work for you. You need to put a separate script in the end of `body` in `index.html` to run on browser:

```
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
    }
  </script>
```

Be aware that this will only give you the basic caching functionality of service worker and will probably not work for `SwPush` or `SwUpdate`. You can check how service worker module works internally [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/service-worker/src/module.ts).

Another thing you should know is, service workers are actually not suitable for SSR apps. The generated `ngsw.json` file will not include all the pages you have. You will have to either modify this file manually or serve it not as a static file but create it dynamically.

And Caching all the pages is not a thing you want to do (unless page contents are static). Because a cached page will always show the same thing since you are not doing an XHR request on client side. For example if your home page is cached for a client, that client will always see the same page regardless of the intended dynamic content.

At this point you should consider why you want SSR and Web APP at the same time. If you need SSR for SEO, you don't need a SW. Just do SSR when the user agent is of a crawler, and serve dynamic angular when the client is a normal user.

**How to switch request based on User Agent**

This is my thought and I don't know if anyone is doing this. But theoretically, it should work.

Firstly, you will have to build your app to two different directories (`DIST_FOLDER/ssr` and `DIST_FOLDER/csr` in my example) with server-side and client-side rendering configurations. You may exclude SW from SSR. You can use SW in CSR as usual.

I found [this package](https://github.com/JefferyHus/es6-crawler-detect) that can detect crawler/bot user agents. For express and Angular, you would use it like:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  var CrawlerDetector = new Crawler(req)

  // check the current visitor's useragent
  if (CrawlerDetector.isCrawler())
  {
    // render the index html at server side
    res.render(path.join(DIST_FOLDER, 'ssr', 'index.html'), { req });
  }
  else {
    // serve static index.html file built without SSR and let the client render it
    res.sendFile(path.join(DIST_FOLDER, 'csr', 'index.html'));
  }
});
```

After implementing this, you can debug your application to see if it works correctly by changing your user agent to one that is written [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) (i.e. use Postman).

Comment: Hi; sounds your answer makes totally sense and it seems that this is the cause of my issue.

I need SSR for SEO and I need Service Worker for Notifications to browser.

How would you suggest to do that?

Comment: P.S: I will credit the 100 Bounty reward in a couple of hours; just want to trigger your attention on my last question on that point.

Comment: @aorfevre Added aditional code showing how to handle the request. Let me know if this works for you as it may be useful for me in the future. For the bounty, reward it whenever you feel suitable.

Comment: Your suggestion is having 2 servers, one for crawler That has ssr, one for client with pwa. If Yes I can handle That with the loadbalancer

Comment: @aorfevre you can use the same server for both. The request you serve will change conditionally. If you are using a CDN with caching, this may be a problem and you may want to use 2 servers. Otherwise you can use the same server for both.

Comment: Managed to do it with this package : https://github.com/binarykitchen/spider-detector

Comment: Thank you, my day is a lot better now :), after a stressfull week of changing our (big) angular site to ssr this is by far the best solution.

Comment: @GökhanKurt what is the command to build app to two different directories? specially with SSR command.

Answer (score 1):

With a little "good-to-have" workaround to [#13351](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13351) got this working on `Angular 10` by quite little change in **main.browser.ts**

```
// Workaround for service worker, issue #13351.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(() => {
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('./ngsw-worker.js');
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

In the `ngsw-config.json` I've edited `index` to refer to `index2.html` instead of `index.html`. That's needed in my case to render SSR on `Firebase`/`NestJS` properly the root (`/`) path.

**ngsw-config.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",      
  "index": "/index2.html",
  ...
}
```

When running with `prod` flag in the `Chrome DevTools` -> `Application` -> `Service Workers` can see it. `View Page Source` shows SSR. I can also add the install the application via Chrome on my desktop. In addition to that, the application works offline. Both, via mobile browser, and desktop app.

Can't why default mobile notification, i.e. `Add to home screen` isn't popping up.

Answer (score -1):

When you Angular PWA (service worker) to Angular SSR project.

> - Kindly add "navigationURLs:[]" in your ngsw-config.json file

The below screen shot will bind SSR html on view source.

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution. Because if you use an empty "navigationURLs" in your ngsw-config.json file, then nothing will be cached.